# hide wp-content from urls

Tags: urls, htaccess, plugin-w3-total-cache, wp-config, settings-api

Here is what I am thinking of trying to hide wp-content from the urls of files included in page source.

defining the following in wp-settings.php

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_URL','http://example.com/myownfoldername');
```

and adding this to `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^myownfoldername/(.*) /wp-content/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This seems to work fine with no additional plugins on localhost `but will it work seamlessly on the online site with a few plugins. I am more concerned about w3 total cache.

I guess I need now worry about a few reference of wp-content in database as even if it exists there it is still a valid link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need a separate rule in your .htaccess. Add …

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'YOUR_LOCAL_PATH' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'YOUR_PUBLIC_PATH' );
```

… to your `wp-config.php`. Do **not** write into `wp-settings.php`. This file will be overwritten during the next update – never touch a core file.

Comment: In the WP_CONTENT_DIR I have to give path to original wp-content folder?

Comment: Using `WP_CONTENT_DIR`, I have to rename the folder to the new directory name. But using .htaccess I can still have directory name as wp-content

Answer (score -1):

## NO NEED TO HIDE!

You will waste energy. it has no secruity.
Read this - https://goo.gl/Pkq8Kn

Comment: while I agree, this is a comment and not an answer